# Android WorkManager build error

Tags: android, android-workmanager

```
e: error: compiler message file broken: key=compiler.err.Processor: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper@719628b5 arguments={0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
e: error: cannot access NetworkType
  class file for androidx.work.NetworkType not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for androidx.work.NetworkType not found
```

Answer (score 1):

how stupid I am, forget to config workmanager in app module, only configured in lib module.